# Change Material UI Stepper icon for error step

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

Im using Material UI's Stepper component to render a checklist like so. This is a pic from their docs.

[image]

when I wanted to introduce an error state to the checklist, I found that there is a prop called error for the StepLabel that I can declare. Basically it will allow you to change the styles such as background color, etc.

However, when I set the error prop to true, there is a new icon that came about. I do not want this icon, but just want to change the fill color from blue to red.
[image]

Is there any way I can forgo that icon and just worry about the fill color of the stepper instead?

Here is my code:

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={this.determineFormStep()} connector={<StepConnector />} className={classes.stepper}>
          {formLabels.map((label, index) => {
            return (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel
                  icon={label.step}
                  error={true}
                  StepIconProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.step,
                      completed: classes.completed,
                      active: classes.active,
                      error: classes.error,
                      disabled: classes.disabled
                    }
                  }}>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel3}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </StepLabel>
              </Step>);
          })}
        </Stepper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put condition on icon props on StepLabel.

`icon={error ? <Error /> : label.step}`
like as mention below

```
Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={this.determineFormStep()} connector={<StepConnector />} className={classes.stepper}>
          {formLabels.map((label, index) => {
            return (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel
                  icon={error ? <Error /> : label.step}
                  error={true}
                  StepIconProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.step,
                      completed: classes.completed,
                      active: classes.active,
                      error: classes.error,
                      disabled: classes.disabled
                    }
                  }}>
                  <div className={classes.stepLabelRoot}>
                    <Typography className={classes.label}>
                      {label.label}
                    </Typography>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel1}
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel2}
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel3}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </StepLabel>
              </Step>);
          })}
        </Stepper>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! May I ask is that <Error /> tag a part of Material UI? Or is it something else?

Comment: @KennyQuach `<Error />` is the material ui icon component. you can import this icon from `@material-ui/icons` for `mui v4` and `@mui/icons-material` for `mui v5`.